# Popover is dismissing by itself

Tags: ios, uialertview, uipopovercontroller

I have tabbed application , in one of my Tab i have a Table View and on selecting any row a Popover will Appear on the screen .
User will enter data in the popover field and i have put a validation code to check the data 
Now if some wrong data is entered by the user then i have called `Alert View`but when alert view appears it automatically disables my Popover.

I want that on canceling the alert view my Popover window will remain visible with the entered vales.

the code for alert view is mentioned below

```
- (IBAction)addTankMixProduct:(id)sender
{
   if (totalPercentage==0 || [self.txtTankmixName.text isEqualToString:@""])
   {
       UIAlertView *myalertview = [
             [UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"warning"
                                  message:@"kindly enter details properly "
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [myalertview show];
       [myalertview release];

    }
    else 
    {
       // SOME CODE TO ENTER DATA 
    }
}
```

what i am doing wrong ??
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying that the popover is automatically dismissed when the alert view is displayed or when the user taps a button on the alert view? Of course neither should have any affect on the popover.

Comment: well i agree with your point but pop over view is disappearing by itself , in one of my Tab it's working fine as we all expect but . in another tab its disappearing huh !! i Dont know why .. ??

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's documentation: "When displayed, taps outside of the popover window cause the popover to be dismissed automatically. To allow the user to interact with the specified views and not dismiss the popover, you can assign one or more views to the passthroughViews property."

You need to assign the alert view to the popover controller's passthroughViews property.

Comment: can you kindly provide me the snippet of code so that i can get you view in detail . Thanks in Advance :)